# Get Alfresco document nodeRef and versionNodeRef together

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.0b.  I have a web application that uses Alfresco for its document store.  Each time I create a new document or update an existing version of a document, I want to store in my application database the document ID and the version ID.  The call to upload the document: 
`POST /alfresco/service/api/upload` works great in that it returns the nodeRef of the newly created document, but it doesn't return the version nodeRef.  To get that, I need to then call: `GET /alfresco/service/api/version?nodeRef={nodeRef}`

Is there a way to get both pieces of information in a single call?

Comment: Why not use CMIS? If you upload through CMIS, you'll get the noderef and version back together

Comment: My reason for not using CMIS so far has been performance.  Every API I've tested so far has been 1/2 the time using the Alfresco Rest API vs. CMIS